# Good lecture series for complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, online-resources

I was wondering if I could teach myself complex analysis. Any good lecture series out there on the internet available for free (preferably)? One that would be suitable for an undergraduate student?

Answer (score 2):

See the [notes by Ash and Novinger](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/CV.html).